# Как распарсить строку php?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, синтаксический-анализ

Вот такая строчка.

```
<a class="history-item product" title="USB Keyboard Leather Cover Case Bag for 7" Tablet PC MID PDA VIA 8650,Free Shipping + Drop Shipping" href="http://www.aliexpress.com/product-gs/495886336-USB-Keyboard-
Leather-Cover-Case-Bag-for-7-Tablet-PC-MID-PDA-VIA-8650-
Free-Shipping-wholesalers.html">USB Keyboard Leather Cover 
Case Bag for 7" Tablet PC MID PDA VIA 8650,Free Shipping + Drop Shipping</a>
```

Из нее надо выдернуть title и саму ссылку, беру между кавычек с помощью именованных частей шаблона.Тут только title и все равно не выходит..как правильно писать?

```
  $pattern7='#<a class="history-item product" title="(?<Cost2>.*)".*#Ui';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ссылке синтаксис не соблюден, двойная ковычка обозначающая дюймы делает закрывающую открывающей,а Tablet PC MID PDA VIA 8650,Free Shipping + Drop Shipping непонятным текстом внутри атрибутов тега,
именно к этому тексту применимо это регулярное выражение:

```
/<a[^>]*title=\"(?<title>[^>]*)\"\s*href=\"(?<url>[^\"]*)\"/i
```

Если бы небыло этой ковычки правильней будет:

```
/<a[^>]*title=\"(?<title>[^\"]*)\"\s*href=\"(?<url>[^\"]*)\"/i
```

Ваше регулярное выражение верно и оно берет эти данные [USB Keyboard Leather Cover Case Bag for 7] это как раз до этой кавычки которая обозначает дюймы

Рабочий код для обработки этого текста:

```
$str='<a class="history-item product" title="USB Keyboard Leather Cover Case Bag for 7" Tablet PC MID PDA VIA 8650,Free Shipping + Drop Shipping" href="http://www.aliexpress.com/product-gs/495886336-USB-Keyboard-Leather-Cover-Case-Bag-for-7-Tablet-PC-MID-PDA-VIA-8650- Free-Shipping-wholesalers.html">USB Keyboard Leather Cover Case Bag for 7" Tablet PC MID PDA VIA 8650,Free Shipping + Drop Shipping</a>';

preg_match('/<a[^>]*title=\"(?<title>[^>]*)\"\s*href=\"(?<url>[^\"]*)\"/i',$str, $match);

echo $match['1'];//вернет текст в title

echo $match['title']; // вернет текст в title

echo $match['2'];//вернет ссылку

echo $match['url'];//вернет ссылку
```

Comment: спасибо,только я не понял что сие означает <a[^>]*
^- это инвентирование же, получается a после нее -не > повторяющаяся 0 или более раз?   Зачем эта конструкция так нужна ?можно же без нее обойтись..

Comment: Это позволяет обойти другие атрибуты в теге стоящие перед title, ведь не всегда там сразу будет сразу стоять title или не всегда будет class="history-item product" (обезопасит от потери данных), а такая конструкция позволяет искать именно в описании этого тега, если в описании нет этого атрибута то preg_match пропустит его как не соответствуещего шаблону.

Comment: Если использовать множестов любых знаков .* как <a.* title..., то можно нарваться на <a class="lalala"> </a> <p title="bububu"...</p>...<a href="gg"... , что не соотвтествует желаемому. [^>]* такая конструкция гарантирует получение результата в любом случае, есть ли атрибуты перед title или нет в описании тега.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь можно испытать:
http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
  $array; 
    $search_string = '<a class="history-item product" title="USB Keyboard Leather Cover Case Bag for 7" Tablet PC MID PDA VIA 8650,Free Shipping + Drop Shipping" href="http://www.aliexpress.com/product-gs/495886336-USB-Keyboard-

    Leather-Cover-Case-Bag-for-7-Tablet-PC-MID-PDA-VIA-8650- Free-Shipping-wholesalers.html">USB Keyboard Leather Cover Case Bag for 7" Tablet PC MID PDA VIA 8650,Free Shipping + Drop Shipping</a>';

    preg_match('/(?<=[t][i][t][l][e][=]["]).+?(?=["])/',$search_string, $array); 
    echo '<br>Здесь title: '; 
    $title = $array[0];
    echo $title;

    $array2;
    preg_match('/(?<=[>]).+?(?=[<])/',$search_string, $array2); 
    echo '<br>Здесь ссылка: '; 
    $link_a = $array2[0];
    echo $link_a;
```